# ASP.NET Core appsettings.json reloadOnChange does not work with symlink file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kubernetes, .net-core

When I use a symlink as the setting file, `reloadOnChange` will not work:

[image]

Actually the symlink is from k8s configMap volumeMounts:

[image]

Is there any solution in ASP.NET Core, or am I just using k8s configMap in a wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the same issue: [36091](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36091)

Writing a [`FileProvider`](https://github.com/fbeltrao/ConfigMapFileProvider/tree/master/src/ConfigMapFileProviderSample) will solve the problem.